# Loop Through a json response in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a json response where i am able to reach through into a single node at this point. I am not able to loop through the response to fetch a particular value i.e. 'PropertyValue' and store it in a list.

Here is the response and the code:

```
{
"documents":[
    {
        "document":[
            {
                "propertyname":"Id",
                "propertyvalue":"{1ED8A008-959D-4D54-9B3D-48F10F5CED85}"
            },
            {
                "propertyname":"DVALinkedDocId",
                "propertyvalue":""
            },
            {
                "propertyname":"DVAPageNumber",
                "propertyvalue":""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "document":[
            {
                "propertyname":"Id",
                "propertyvalue":"{FCDACA2E-98BD-4E7F-BB4B-F1A543B40E3A}"
            },
            {
                "propertyname":"DVALinkedDocId",
                "propertyvalue":""
            },
            {
                "propertyname":"DVAPageNumber",
                "propertyvalue":""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "document":[
            {
                "propertyname":"Id",
                "propertyvalue":"{3DC1C70F-35AE-43AA-8CEC-FACE3ACEA519}"
            },
            {
                "propertyname":"DVALinkedDocId",
                "propertyvalue":""
            },
            {
                "propertyname":"DVAPageNumber",
                "propertyvalue":""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "document":[
            {
                "propertyname":"Id",
                "propertyvalue":"{B397323D-C0D4-4DA2-A95A-A79C3842D2DE}"
            },
            {
                "propertyname":"DVALinkedDocId",
                "propertyvalue":""
            },
            {
                "propertyname":"DVAPageNumber",
                "propertyvalue":""
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GuidResponse));
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(responseData)))
{
     var response = (GuidResponse)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
     foreach (var obj in response.documents)
     {
          foreach (var docObj in obj.document)
          {
              string Guid = docObj.propertyvalue;
          }
     }
}
```

The Problem is i want to show all the guid property values in a list but i am not able to do that with the above code.

Comment: What is in `GuidResponse` and what is `responseData`'s value?

Comment: Does it produce an error? What value does it return to your `Guid` variable?

Comment: @Oluwafemi "1ED8A008-959D-4D54-9B3D-48F10F5CED85" and similar values in the response are the guid values. I want to make a collection of the guids coming in the response.
The responsedata is the json response pasted above.

Comment: @MatchesMalone It's showing the first Guid value in the response.We could use dictionary to store the value of id and Property value but i am not sure how to do it.
I could later get the values out of the dictionary.

Comment: Do you just want `var list = response.documents.SelectMany(d => d.document).Select(o => o.propertyvalue).ToList();`

Comment: @dbc I am able to get all the property values with the above code. Is there any way to remove the propertyvalues that have empty value i.e. 
"propertyvalue":"" shouldn't be there in the list.

Comment: @dbc Thank you! I just added the where condition with !string.IsNullOrEmpty and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a string type array or list that holds all object you are passing to c# program through Json.
Create a model class in C# and dis serialize  data to that model.

```
string[] AchievementsList = Regex.Matches(strAchievements, @"\{.*?\}").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
for (i = 0; i < AchievementsList.Length; i++)
{
    TestClass aJson = js.Deserialize<TestClass>(AchievementsList[i]); //use aJson object to access properties you  need 
}
```

Class for holding object of json type

```
class TestClass
{
    public  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did you tried to  solve your problem using this approach

Comment: Actually, I used one of the linq expressions mentioned above.I just modified that and it worked for me. Thank you for your support anyway.

Comment: Parsing json with regex is a very bad idea. Take this json for example `{"data":"{0}={1}"}` , your regex will fail...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 var list = response.documents.SelectMany(d => d.document).Select(o => o.propertyvalue).Where(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use JSON.Net -

```
public class Document2
{
    public string propertyname { get; set; }
    public string propertyvalue { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public List<Document2> document { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Document> documents { get; set; }
}
```

And then -

```
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(new StreamReader("json").ReadToEnd());



var list = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in o.documents)
{
    list.Add(item.document[0].propertyvalue);
}
```